# mount info for current directory

Tags: filesystems, mount, disk-usage

I can do `df .` to get some of the info on the mount that the current directory is in, and I can get all the info I want from `mount`. However, I get too much info (info about other mounts). I can grep it down, but I am wondering if there is a better way.

Is there some command `mountinfo` such that `mountinfo .` gives the info I want (like `df .` but with the info that `mount` gives)?

---

I am using Debian GNU/Linux.

Comment: I believe `stat` command can be used as well. However, I am not sure if `%m` option which gives the mount point is supported in your version of system. I checked in my system and it seemed to not return the mount point.

Comment: @Ramesh, Yes `stat "--printf=%m\n" .` gets the mount-point of the file-system that the current directory is in. Thus allowing us to simplify some of the answers. Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167558/give-the-mount-point-of-a-path/59130628 and https://serverfault.com/questions/66492/in-nix-how-to-determine-which-filesystem-a-particular-file-is-on

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
findmnt -T .
```

When using the option

```
-T, --target path
```

if the path is not a mountpoint file or directory, `findmnt` checks  path  elements in reverse order to get the mountpoint. You can print only certain fields via `-o, --output [list]`.
See `findmnt --help` for the list of available fields.

---

Alternatively, you could run:

```
(until findmnt . ; do cd .. ; done)
```

The problem you're running into is that all paths are relative to something or other, so you just have to walk the tree. Every time.

`findmnt` is a member of the util-linux package and has been for a few years now. By now, regardless of your distro, it should already be installed on your Linux machine if you also have the `mount` tool.

```
man mount | grep findmnt -B1 -m1
For  more robust and customizable output use
findmnt(8),  especially  in  your   scripts.
```

`findmnt` will print out all mounts' info without a mount-point argument, and only that for its argument with one. The `-D` is the *emulate `df`* option. Without `-D` its output is similar to `mount`'s - but far more configurable. Try `findmnt --help` and see for yourself.

I stick it in a subshell so the current shell's current directory doesn't change.

So:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/1/2/3/4/5/6 && cd $_ 
(until findmnt . ; do cd .. ; done && findmnt -D .) && pwd
```

#### OUTPUT

```
TARGET SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
/tmp   tmpfs  tmpfs  rw
SOURCE FSTYPE  SIZE   USED AVAIL USE% TARGET
tmpfs  tmpfs  11.8G 839.7M   11G   7% /tmp
/tmp/1/2/3/4/5/6
```

If you do not have the `-D` option available to you *(Not in older versions of util-linux)* then you need never fear - it is little more than a convenience switch in any case. Notice the column headings it produces for each call - you can include or exclude those for each invocation with the `-o`utput switch. I can get the same output as `-D` might provide like:

```
 findmnt /tmp -o SOURCE,FSTYPE,SIZE,USED,AVAIL,USE%,TARGET
```

#### OUTPUT

```
SOURCE FSTYPE  SIZE  USED AVAIL USE% TARGET
tmpfs  tmpfs  11.8G  1.1G 10.6G  10% /tmp
```

Comment: I like it, except the bit about `-D`, I don't have that option. (I am on Debian7, util-linux 2.20.1-5.3)

Comment: I will √ you in a few days, I will leave some time to see if anyone has a more perfect answer. Though this is close to perfect (if it worked like df: did not need the loop, then it would be perfect).

Comment: @richard - that's a good idea - I don't like it when answers get accepted too soon. regarding the loop and `df` - I'm willing to bet it does loop, you just don't have to tell it to do so.

Comment: @richard I made an edit in light of your not having the `-D` switch.

Comment: Thanks to @ramesh we can also do `findmnt $(stat "--printf=%m\n" .)`

Comment: `-D` was added in `util-linux` version 2.22; Debian is still on 2.20: Debian prefers stability over novelty, so is usually a bit behind.

Comment: My version of `findmnt` has a `-T` option that can bypass the `cd ..` loop.  Might be useful to someone else.

Comment: @nitrogen - yes. please make that an answer. that switch has been added since this was published, and possibly even as a result of its publishing.

Comment: I am currently on Debian oldstable (Jessie), it has both of these new switches.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, Debians prefers necrophilia over usual relations.

Comment: Can you elaborate if `findmnt` correctly handles `mount -o bind ...` and *OverlayFS* cases?

Comment: @0andriy ..que?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, *Debian prefers stability over novelty...* — this is simple bs. They can't manage distro, that's it. They have really odd practices of what is to update and how. Their point of view to the, for example, kernel security is ridiculous... But. yes, it's my private opinion as user of Debian (unstable, because of above concerns). Why am I sitting on it? To know what is going on (I use different distros on different machines)

Comment: @0andriy I think I groked some of that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a command, but you could create a function. You can add the below to your `.bashrc`:

```
mountinfo () {
  mount | grep $(df -P "$1" | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')
}
```

This executes the `mount` command and passes the output to `grep`. `grep` will look for the output of `df -P "$1" | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`, and to break it down:

- `df -P "$1"` will run `df` on the argument passed to the function,
- `tail -n 1` will only output the second line, the one that contains the `partition` info.
- `awk '{print $1}'` will print the first part of that line, which is the disk/partition number, for example `/dev/sda5`. That's what `grep` will look for in the mount command, and output it.

Source your `.bashrc` file to apply the changes, or log out and log back in.

Now, if you run `mountinfo .`, you'll get the output you want.

Comment: This is pretty much what I have been doing (but without the function, I don't do it enough, when I do it is on other systems e.g. answers on this site. ), it is just that `mount` with no options seem a bit of an after thought: with options you create mount points, without it lists them, I was hoping for a better list tool. As we see @mikeserv has shown us `findmnt`.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux/Unix way is to have a toolbox of small utilities that, when combined, give you the results that you're after.

They tend not to have an utility for every occassion. Instead you have many small useful utilities that are combined together with pipes etc.  The advantage of this is that you can write your own utility quite easily if none are available.

For example, to get the info you're after, you could use:

```
mount | grep $(df  --output=source . | tail -1)
```

If you want to reuse the above with different directories, create a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount | grep $(df  --output=source $1 | tail -1)
```

Save it as `mountinfo` and make it executable (`chmod +x mountinfo`).  You can then use it as:

```
mountinfo .
```

If you want a system that has an utility for everything none of which interoperate with each other, then a certain Mr Gates may be able to help you ;-)

Comment: `--output` only exists in very recent versions of GNU coreutils (≥8.22).

Comment: This is pretty much what I have been doing, it is just that `mount` with no options seem a bit of an after thought: with options you create mount points, without it lists them, I was hoping for a better list tool. As we see @mikeserv has shown us `findmnt`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be somewhat messy if the mount points contain blanks, but this should work except in cases where the mount points contain newlines:

```
#!/bin/sh
mountpoint="$(df -P "$1" | awk '{
    if (NR==1)
        i=index($0,"Mounted on");
    else
        print substr($0,i);
    }')"
mount|grep " on ${mountpoint} type "
```

`df -P` outputs one line for the filesystem; without that option, `df` may output two lines if the mount point is long. The mount point name starts in the same column as does the "Mounted on" label in the header line.

After we get the mount point, we grep for it in the output of `mount`.

Answer (score 0):

If you using a not completely ancient version of the GNU coreutils df, then `echo $(df . --output=target | tail -n 1)` works.  Likewise with `stat -c '%m' .`, although I note that https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat lacks documentation of the `%m` format option.

Doing this portably is tiresome: neither of the above will work with the BSD or Cygwin versions of stat or df. If it weren't for the possibility of spaces in the paths of mount points, `df -P .  | tail -1 | awk '{ print $NF}'` would be good, but often USB flash drives have spaces in the volume name, which will probably appear in the mount path and break this. For portability, Perl is installable practically everywhere and CPAN has the module [Sys::Filesystem::MountPoint](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sys::Filesystem::MountPoint) which provides the desired functionality.

Comment: Can you tell us what the `echo $()` adds to the command?

Comment: `df -P . | tail -1 | awk '{ print $NF}'` is the only command that worked on `LibreELEC v11.0.3`