# android partition and kernel 3.14

Tags: mount, partition

I mount a cell phone to my debian i can browse android `SD card` and `internal memory`, So i the following output of mount command when i browse android `sd card`:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=207517,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1226480k,mode=755)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a14aae90-33de-4707-afce-9fdfbd6cd7d2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=34,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=102400k,mode=755)
/dev/sda3 on /archives/ISOs type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

**NOTE:** sda3 is my partition on my laptop.

*my question is* where's mount point of android?

**UPDATE:** 
I can browse with GUI, but can't find its `mount point`, i done the following commands:

```
root@debian:~# df -a > df.mounted   ##### When cell phone is connected 
root@debian:~# df -a > df.unmounted   #### When cell phone is disconnected
diff -u df.mounted df.unmounted
```

But i didn't any difference between two files.

My systesm:

```
root@debian:~# uname -a
Linux debian 3.14-2-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.14.15-2 (2014-08-09) i686 GNU/Linux
root@debian:~# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux jessie/sid \n \l
```

Comment: I'd guess the fuse one – do any of these go away if you don't connect the phone?

Comment: While revisiting the question, I have suddenly realised what you question is (probably). Are you trying to access files on the android device, and just simply need to know where it is mounted, so that you can do this?

Comment: @richard yes, i need to browse with cd,ls and etc , but i don't know its mount point.

Comment: Come join me for a chat, about this question. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16687/android-partition-and-kernel-3-14

Comment: you can drag-and-drop the icons to the terminal to paste their full path

Comment: I think it is because your device is using mtp. This may be related http://askubuntu.com/questions/376815/how-to-connect-mtp-android-device-to-ubuntu-13-10 I can not remember how to mount mtp devices, probably a fuse module.

Comment: mtp://[usb:002,008]/

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: @PythoNic , You vote up, it's a protocol between some devices such as android and computer

Comment: maybe you should ask on (http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

See here [mount info for current directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149660/mount-info-for-current-directory) This question answers how to find mount info for file-system for current working directory.

So if you can cd to somewhere in the mount, then you can find out with `(cd $somewhereInTheMount; until findmnt . ; do cd .. ; done)`

Comment: When cell phone connected i use `df -a > df.mounted` , Then i disconnected cele phone and i use `df -a > df.unmounted` , Then i use `diff -u df.mounted df.umounted` , But two files same together. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you try my idea in the answer? What happened?

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh `df -a` may not be reliable . Use `cat /proc/mounts` instead