# Command for getting path to mount point of current partition/drive?

Tags: filesystems, mount, directory, command

Is there an alternative command that does the same thing as `findmnt -T . -o TARGET |tail -n 1`?

Example: If my current working directory is `/media/username/HDD/subdir1/subdir2`, that command would output `/media/username/HDD/`.

In Windows, the path to the highest directory of the current drive/partition is `\` (also `/` works in *cmd*), because Windows does work with drive letters instead of ["everything is a file"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file).

Unix works more unified and modular, but how can one find to the mount point of a partition? If there is no shorter solution than `findmnt -T . -o TARGET |tail -n 1`, it is no problem. I just wanted to know whether there is a different way.

Comment: isn't `mount` will not solve your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mount info for current directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149660/mount-info-for-current-directory)

Comment: @roaima No, your edit was correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at `man findmnt` I see a number of suggestions that seem to do what you want when finding the mount point for a filesystem:

```
findmnt --first-only --noheadings --output TARGET --target "$PWD"
/home
```

Or with less readability:

```
findmnt -fno TARGET -T "$PWD"
/home
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to find it for yourself, not for later use in a variable. you won't find a shorter way than `df .`:

```
$ df . 
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6      343650580 232263752  93860660  72% /home
```

That has extra details, of course, so can't be used to just save the device name to a variable directly. However, it's very easy to parse:

```
$ df . | grep -Po '^/\S+'
/dev/sda6
$ df . | awk '/^\//{print $1}'
/dev/sda6
```

But if you really want a single command to print it, then [@roaima's `findmnt`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523695/22222) will be the best.

Comment: `df` can be real pain to parse. If you have a sufficiently long device name (LVM) the output can be split across two lines.

Comment: @roaima ooh, true, I hadn't even thought of LVM names. Still, the device should at least never have whitespace, so on GNU systems, the `df . | grep -Po '^/\S+'` should work. But yeah, `findmt` is a safer choice. I just like `df .` since it's so short and perfectly adequate for human consumption.