# How to get UUID of filesystem given a path?

Tags: linux, shell, block-device, uuid

I am handed a path of a directory or a file.

Which utility/shell script will reliably give me the UUID of the file system on which is this directory/file located?

By UUID of file system I mean the `UUID=...` entry as shown by e.g. `blkid`

I'm using Redhat Linux.

(someone suggested that I should ask this here at unix.stackexchange.com, so I moved it from the original stackexchange.com)

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11311/how-do-i-find-on-which-physical-device-a-folder-is-located on how to get the filesystem, following which you can run `blkid`.

Comment: Note that not all file systems will have a UUID; blkid won't give you a UUID eg. for NFS mounts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is `stat` + `findmnt` combo:

```
findmnt -n -o UUID $(stat -c '%m' "$path")
```

Here `-n` disables header, and `-o UUID` prints only UUID value. Option `-c '%m'` of `stat` is present to output only mountpoint of given path.

Comment: There's no need for `stat`: `findmnt -no uuid -T "$path"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use df to find the file's mount point, and then apply the result to blkid to the the UUID. You need to run (at least) blkid as root for this to work:

```
FILE_OR_DIR="$PWD"
blkid -s UUID -o value $( df "$FILE_OR_DIR" )
```

Comment: Better would be `-o export`, since that prints output of the form `UUID=...`.

Comment: @muru it wasn't clear to me whether just the UUID was required (`-o value`) or a `UUID="value"` type expression (`-o export`). I chose value.